# Creating Android based web application for windows

Tags: android

I'm interested in creating an Android based web application for windows. To create a mobile app I understand we need the following tools for setting up a development environment:

1. IDE (Eclipse)
2. JDK and JRE.
3. SDK.
4. ADT and AVD.
5. Database (SQLite).

The AVD (Android Virtual Device) is an emulator to give us an environment similar to one of Android smart phone.

But I need to develop a web application for windows. So

1. What are the prerequisites I should be taking care of for setting up a development environment?
2. Do I require an AVD for developing Android based web apps?

Comment: @Sathya: please use `code markdown` only for code, not for parts of sentences.

Comment: what exactly you want to do android or windows phone

Comment: what exactly is your question? are you trying to develop android application or windows application? the tools that you mentioned are enough to develop many android apps. but if you are trying for web based application you might need some more tools depending on requirements. i would ask you to elaborate your question.